# Are double quotes being replaced in titles?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, title

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Smart quotes in parentheses point the wrong way (“example”) [“tst”] {“tst”}](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34587/smart-quotes-in-parentheses-point-the-wrong-way-example-tst-tst)

I've edited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145509/why-does-abcd-startswith-return-true) to change the `“ ”` to `""`, however it keeps reverting back to `“”`.

Is this a chrome issue, parser, my cache, a bug or maybe intended? Obviously “ ” aren't valid quotes for some text editors or for a programming language.

Comment: Can't reproduce with Firefox 3.5.6

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate, but I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: Looks like question titles have some kind of smart-quotes that aren't necessarily appropriate for a programming site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's no bug, it's a [feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34587/smart-quotes-in-parentheses-point-the-wrong-way-example-tst-tst).