# Can we make the smart quoting algorithm for titles even smarter?

Tags: feature-request, title

Quotes in titles are automatically converted to 'smart' quotes: [Are double quotes being replaced in titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38098/295232)

There are various cases where this is not desirable, e.g. when using them to indicate feet (') or inches ("). An example is here: [Replace 27.5 x 3" MTB tires with 27.5 x 2.1"](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/66246/19567), whose title renders as

> Replace 27.5 x 3“ MTB tires with 27.5 x 2.1”

If the opening quote is directly followed by anything else than a letter or a number, it's unlikely to be an actual quote. The same logic is already applied to the post markdown when it comes to e.g. italics:

```
This is a* test*
```

is rendered as

> This is a* test*

Comment: I’d call this a bug-fix request more than I would a feature request :)

Comment: @Shadow9 technically speaking, this is not an automated edit; the title is stored in the database with straight quotes but *rendered* with smart quotes.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. So yeah, guess the tag can go.